# How Do I List All The Members In A Server

Tags: discord.js

So I'm Having A Problem I Want To See How Many Members My Server Has But It Only Shows 5 I Have More Than 5 Members My Server My Code Is

```
message.member.guild.members.cache.size
```

Is There A Way To Fix This? Or Am I Doing Something Wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the total count of the members in a guild is to use `guild.memberCount`.

```js
let membercount = message.guild.memberCount
message.channel.send(membercount + " members in this guild.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cache the members. The quicker way to do it is like this:

```js
let members = await message.guild.members.fetch();
let amount = members.size; //should give the correct amount
```

The `fetch()` method returns a promise, the collection of members in the guild. You must await it though.

Remember to put it in an `async` function!

Answer (score 0):

You can choose this

```
let members = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter(m => !m.user.bot); //Filter only the Members
let membersAmount = members.size; //give the correct amount
```

instead `message.member.guild.members.cache.size`